# How do I combine multiple hard drives without losing any content in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have 4 hard drives in my computer, one windows drive `C:`, and other `D`,`E`,`F`, total capacity being 500 GB. I have windows 7 home basic installed on my system.

I want to re-install windows and increase my windows `C:` capacity from 74 GB to more, by combining my `C:` and `D:`.

I also do not want to lose my `E:` and `F:` contents. I don't care if `D:` contents are lost.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Just delete the partition then merge the free space with C.  I would backup all data before you did this of course.

Comment: Do you have 4 physical hard drives or 4 partitions on one hard drive?

Comment: Agreed, this is confusing. Do you have 4 partitions on one drive, across multiple drives, or do you have 4 physical disks? Please clarify the scenario in your question.

Answer (score 3):

I understood that you have 4 *partitions* in one HD, with letters C:, D:, E: and F:, that's right?

If so, you can do the following:

1. backup everything, because there's always the chance of something go wrong
2. Open the `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools`
3. Open the `Computer Management`, and then select Disk Management.
4. You'll see your `Disk0` and all the drive letters associated to it.
5. Look which partition/letter goes after the C:. That will be deleted afterwards. For example, let's assume it is the D:
6. Open the `Windows Explorer` and move everything from the D: to another drive (to E: or F:)
7. Close `Windows Explorer` and go back to the `Computer Management`
8. Right-click the D:, and `delete volume`.
9. Right-click the C:, and `Extend Volume`

And that's it, now your d: drive is gone and C: has increased. And if you're lucky, you haven't lost anything. Otherwise, use the backup from the first step and restore your files...

Comment: If the user is looking to reinstall windows (upgrade) this can be done when the installation disc boots

Comment: @Raystafarian the deleting and expanding partitions can be done in the installer, but not the backup of the D:\ contents (step 6)

Comment: @ernie you're right. I made an edit that changed the question. Rolled it back. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you would need to do is back up all the data.  Any way you're going to do it, you're going to end up wiping out all the drives.  My recommendation would be to purchase an external hard drive that's at least 500GB in size and back up all important data to it.

After that is done, re-install Windows like you want. NOTE: You can't extend the C: drive onto other disks without a 3rd-party utility.

After Windows is done installing, follow these steps on the 2nd-4th drives: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57378002-285/how-to-turn-old-hard-drives-into-one-large-drive-in-windows/

You'll end up with 2 drives, C: and D:.  C: will have the same amount of space it has now, and D: will have the rest.  Personally, I prefer to have the drives separated like this and keep all my data on D:, so I can reformat Windows without losing anything important at any time.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If ANY of the drives in the spanned volume fail, you lose all data on them.  Proceed at your own risk.